# Need help debugging a print statement (matrix):

Tags: debugging, matrix

So I have this program that I am working on. Here is the code so far:

```
A = [[2,4], [7,0], [6,3]]
B = [[3,1], [-1,8], [-3, 3]]

def Print(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        line = "\t|"+str(A[i][0])
        for j in range(1, len(A[i])):
            line = line + "\t" + str(A[i][j])
        line = line + "|"
        print(line)

def matrix_add(A,B):
    Z = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        row = []
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            row.append(A[i][j]+B[i][j])
        Z.append(row)
    return Z

print("A + B:")
Print(matrix_add(A,B))
```

The print statement I am getting is this:

```
A + B:
        |5    5|
        |6    8|
        |3    6|
```

But the print statement I need is:

```
A + B:
     |5      5|
     |6      8|
     |3      6|
```

See how the matrix is closer towards the A+B:
How would I fix my program to do this? I cant figure it out.

I tried adding spaces to the `line = "\t|"+str(A[i][0])` so it changed to `line = "    |"+str(A[i][0])` but that just changed the print statement to:

```
A + B:
    |5   5|
    |6   8|
    |3   6|
```

and I need it to look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the many String formatting options Python has.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

```
def Print(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        line = "{0: >6}".format("|"+str(A[i][0]))
        for j in range(1, len(A[i])):
            line = line + "{0: >4}".format(str(A[i][j]))
        line = line + "|"
        print(line)
```

If you input a bigger number, such as `10`, the indent goes off by one. You can determine the length of the string to be formatted, and use the length to make it more versatile.

Comment: ~(^O^)~ ahhh geeez thank you soooo much!!! it works perfectly with using `line = "{0: >7}".format("|"+str(A[i][0]))` and `line = line + "{0: >7}".format(str(A[i][j]))` youre awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

In this first line here:

line = "\t|"+str(A[i][0])

You'll want to change the tab (\t) to something that doesn't move it as far out. Maybe a few spaces?

Comment: I tried changing the \t but it just took away the space in between the matrix. `A - B:
    |-1 3|
    |8 -8|
    |9 0|` i guess it doesnt show well on here..

Comment: You'll only want to remove the \t from the first place it appears. \t is the whitespace character for a tab. However, as you can see from Sami's post, Python has much more powerful ways of manipulating strings.